# What is the significance of the license plate number on the Ford Anglia in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, the-chamber-of-secrets

In Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, the flying Ford Anglia has a license plate number of 7990 TD. Is there any significance to this, or were those digits just randomly selected?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer given to a somewhat similar question posted on SciFi a couple years back, they appear to be random:

[Is there any significance to the licence plates on the Ford Anglia?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129710/is-there-any-significance-to-the-licence-plates-on-the-ford-anglia/129715#129715)

There is a link in one of the answers that shows the tag was the actual registration tag (the link is to a news story of the car being reported stolen from a studio lot).